# remove escape sequences from string in php

Tags: php, string, escaping

I'm working with a mysqldump file that has escaped character sequences. I need to know the length of a string as its database value, but the dump has escape characters in it, which add length to the string.

I've used `stripslashes()` which properly un-escapes single- and double-quotes, but it doesn't touch the `\r\n`.

I'm concerned there are other escaped character sequences in there that I'm not aware of. Is there a function I can use that will give me the true length of the string as it would be in the database? If I have to build my own function, what other sequences should it handle?

Comment: Actually, stripslashes changes `\r\n` into `rn`. That adds 2 to the length of the string, which is a correct value, because `\r\n\` are actually two characters in the string, even though they aren't literally `rn`. Hm...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [strip **c** slashes()](http://php.net/stripcslashes) function does exactly that:

```
stripcslashes('foo\r\n');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`substr_count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) to count characters in a string. Simply count how many backslashes are in the string:

```
$string = "... mysqldump string here ...";
$backslashes = substr_count($string, '\\');
```

That'll give you a rough count. To be 100% accurate, you'd have to count how many double backslashes there are, to account for literal backslashes, and adjust the count as appropriate.